# Angular cli specific path while generating component

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am having multiple apps in my angular project. 
I want to generate component in my app by specifying the path. I am trying the below command:

```
ng g c shared/test-component --dry-run
```

But Angular Cli creates the component at path

```
src/app/shared/test
```

I don't want angular cli to add 'src/app' to the path I supply. How can I restrict it?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can. Components have to be in the src/app directory. Why do you want to change this?

Comment: because I have multiple apps in my app and src/app is not relevant to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple apps, you can specify which one you want to use using the `--app` flag, and specify either the app name or the app index

```
ng g c shared/test-component --dry-run --app 1
```

But the generated code will still be under `src/appName`